# How to map a many-to-many relationship between 2 views?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

Basically I have a search that is using a big sql view to retrieve data and now I have to extend the search functionality to another field taken from a separate view.

I have followed the steps here in this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) but I got stuck.

I want to create a many to many relationship between the views V_FPDA_FILE_RTL_UNT and V_FPDA_FILE_UK_CONTN.

I have the table FpdaFileDetail mapped to the V_FPDA_FILE_RTL_UNT view.

```
@Entity(name="FpdaFileDetail")
@Table(name="V_FPDA_FILE_RTL_UNT")
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "FPDA_FILE_ID")) })
public class FpdaFileDetail {

...

@ManyToMany
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "V_FPDA_FILE_UK_CONTN", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FPDA_FILE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "UK_CMPT_CONTN_ID")})
    public Set<UkComponentContent> getUkContentIds() {
        return ukContentIds;
    }

    public void setUkContentIds(Set<UkComponentContent> ukContentIds) {
        this.ukContentIds = ukContentIds;

}
```

The many to many relation that I have created is made like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UK_CONTN")
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "UK_CONTN_ID")) })
public class UkContent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String contentId;
    private Set<UkComponentContent> ukComponentContents;


    @Column(name = "UK_CONTN")
    public String getContentId() {
        return contentId;
    }

    public void setContentId(String contentId) {
        this.contentId = contentId;
    }

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "ukContent",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
        )
    public Set<UkComponentContent> getUkComponentContents() {
        return ukComponentContents;
    }

    public void setUkComponentContents(Set<UkComponentContent> ukComponentContents) {
        this.ukComponentContents = ukComponentContents;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity(name = "FpdaFile")
@Table(name = "FPDA_FILE")
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "FPDA_FILE_ID")) })
public class FpdaFile {
...
    private Set<UkComponentContent> ukContentIds = new HashSet<UkComponentContent>(0);

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fpdaFile")
    public Set<UkComponentContent> getUkContentIds() {
        return ukContentIds;
    }

    public void setUkContentIds(Set<UkComponentContent> ukContentIds) {
        this.ukContentIds = ukContentIds;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UK_CMPT_CONTN")
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "UK_CMPT_CONTN_ID")) })
public class UkComponentContent extends BaseEntity {
    private FpdaFile fpdaFile;
    private UkContent ukContent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FPDA_FILE_ID")
    public FpdaFile getFpdaFile() {
        return fpdaFile;
    }

    public void setFpdaFile(FpdaFile fpdaFile) {
        this.fpdaFile = fpdaFile;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UK_CONTN_ID")
    public UkContent getUkContent() {
        return ukContent;
    }
    public void setUkContent(UkContent ukContent) {
        this.ukContent = ukContent;
    }


}
```

The thing is that if I let the code like this, the search won't work but it won't throw any error. From debugging I realized that if I comment this ( from FpdaFileDetail)..

```
@ManyToMany
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "V_FPDA_FILE_UK_CONTN", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FPDA_FILE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "UK_CMPT_CONTN_ID")})
    public Set<UkComponentContent> getUkContentIds() {
        return ukContentIds;
    }

    public void setUkContentIds(Set<UkComponentContent> ukContentIds) {
        this.ukContentIds = ukContentIds;
```

the search will work. But with it uncommented, it does not work.

Any idea is welcome!